# how to set start date and end date in linked pickers for Bootstrap v3 Datetimepicker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I need to set TO field to restrict any date selection earlier than FROM field.

Tried setMinDate,setMaxDate, minDate and maxDate. But nothing works.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#date').datetimepicker({
        ......
        minDate: moment(new Date())
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an example of [Linked Pickers](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#linked-pickers) on the docs site.

It is easily done with this code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class='col-md-5'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker6'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-5'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker7'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker({
            format: 'LT',
            minDate:moment('2/25/2015 09:00')
        });
        $('#datetimepicker7').datetimepicker({
            format: 'LT',
            maxDate:moment('2/25/2015 18:00')
        });
        $("#datetimepicker6").on("dp.change",function (e) {
            $('#datetimepicker7').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
        });
        $("#datetimepicker7").on("dp.change",function (e) {
            $('#datetimepicker6').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: My code supports "change.dp" event. I tried code sample as suggested by no break through.

Comment: I tried my code with the fiddle but no help. Below is my code snippet:

Comment: $(function () {
      $('#start').datetimepicker({
        pickTime: false,
        pickDate: true,
        autoclose: true,
        format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
      });
      
       $("#start").on("change.dp",function (e) {
       var startdate = new Date(e.date.valueOf());
       alert(startdate);       
      });
      $('#stop').datetimepicker({
        pickTime: false,
        pickDate: true,
        autoclose: true,
        format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
      });
      
      $("#stop").on("change.dp",function (e) {
       alert("2");
      });
    });

Comment: V4 removed the `pickTime/pickDate` options. v4 uses the `format` string to determine what components to show. The console show several errors with your code. I suggest reading [the docs](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

Comment: Thanks for the update. Could you suggest me any link for V3 docs as we cannot go for V4.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I checked this:  eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/version2 and found the correct methods. How can I set "End Date" to be as same as "Start Date" using setStartDate(e.date) method. That means if I select 19 Feb 2015 in Start date field, End date field should be enabled for the selection of 19 Feb 2015 and not prior to that.

Comment: hi, could you help me out?

Comment: why are you using v2? It's not possible to set the start/end dates to the same day in v2. You can do that in the latest.

Comment: Actually I used V2 quite long back. Ok, Let me know how do I set the start/end dates to the same day in V4?

Comment: I'v'e updated the code in my answer. Give that a shot